# Deploying Microsoft Bot to Azure Not working with Azure CLI

Tags: botframework, azure-cli

I'm following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=userassigned%2Cnewgroup%2Ccsharp) tutorial to deploy a Microsoft Bot to Azure. Under "Create an identity resource" it says to use this Azure CLI command:

```
az ad app create --display-name "<name>" --password "<password>"
```

Running this command gives the error:

```
unrecognized arguments: --password
```

On the tutorial page it gives a link to the az ad app command reference, looking at the reference for az ad app create, it lists all flags you can use with the command, and --password is not on the list. I'm not sure what to do at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Azure CLI are you running? Version 2.37.0 made breaking changes to the CLI commands. The document you referenced specifies earlier versions of Azure CLI to use depending on your language of choice. The az ad app reference is also linked to the latest version, so naturally `--password` is not shown.

Comment: I'm using version 2.38.0, so that makes sense. I'll use an earlier version of the CLI.